# SQL Server CREATE USER with Parameters (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to execute CREATE USER with a given username (via sql parameter)

```
exec sp_executesql N'CREATE USER @LoginName 
                        FOR LOGIN @LoginName;',
                   N'@LoginName varchar(5)', @LoginName='myuser'
```

Heres the code thats generating the above:

```
Dim myCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("CREATE USER @LoginName 
                                                 FOR LOGIN @LoginName;", 
                                             ClassDatabaseConnection.CustomInstance)
myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@LoginName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = LoginName
myCommand.ExecuteScalar()
```

I get and error:

```
Incorrect syntax near '@LoginName'.
```

I think this is due to the parameters being passed as VarChar causing 'MyUser' rather than MyUser

Can I not do this with sql parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use parameters with a `Create User` statement. Since you're already in VB, try piecing together a statement.

```
Dim myCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("CREATE USER " + LoginName +
                                                " FOR LOGIN " + LoginName + ";", 
                                             ClassDatabaseConnection.CustomInstance)
myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
myCommand.ExecuteScalar()
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid this due to SQL injection.

Comment: @madlan, duely noted, but you can always check for mal-characters in your login name before submitting. Semi-colon, quotes, and double hyphens are a good starting point. Personally, I never allow these characters in usernames anyways.

Answer (score 3):

As noted, you can't parameterize a CREATE LOGIN.

To avoid SQL injection (also as noted), consider using [SMO Login.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.login.create%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm using .net 4 so cannot use SMO at the moment.

Comment: You'd use dmo for 2000.  But CREATE LOGIN or USER is SQL Server 2005+

Comment: SMO appears to be ok with 2000 (SSMS uses it when connected to a 2000 instance).